# Cannot build C++ projects - "Object of type X cannot be converted to type Y"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

This is freshly installed Visual Studio 2015 RC on fresh Windows 8.1 install.

When I try to compile anything, even simplest C program, I get the following build error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Object of type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1[System.IO.StreamReader]' cannot be converted to type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1[System.IO.TextWriter]'.
1>Error: Object of type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1[System.IO.StreamReader]' cannot be converted to type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1[System.IO.TextWriter]'.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas what's the problem here?

EDIT: Sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot compile "Hello world"? Something wrong with your installation maybe.

Comment: Not without seeing your actual code. It would seem you have a bug in your code, where it is trying to assign an `ExportFactory<StreamReader>` to a `ExportFactory<TextWriter>`.

Comment: No, really simplest C program possible. ANY program for that matter. I also suspect some installation problem, but this is fresh install on fresh system...

Comment: It looks like Visual Studio is *encountering* an error, not informing you of an error in your code. Try repairing the installation or finding another version.

Comment: Will it compile the Release configuration?

Comment: Started happening after installing windows updates.